# Always playing css animation when adding/removing class from div

Tags: javascript, css, animation, webkit, css-animations

at the moment I move a div by adding/removing a class (`playing`), which is working perfectly.
Now I want this to be more smooth and thought about adding some css animations.
The problem is, I dont understand how to add an animation, which is playing when Im either removing or adding this class. Is this even possible?

```
.description-container {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -11%;
}

.description-container.playing {
    margin-top: 0%;
}
```

I tried this for the transition from top to bottom (the result of adding the playing class to my div), but it didnt work:

```
.description-container.playing {
    animation: top-to-bottom 1s ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes top-to-bottom {
    100% {
        margin-top: 0%;
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you looking for CSS transition?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, if its possible here. I added what Ive tried so far but didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For animations, you can use the CSS attribute `transition`.
Have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).

In your example, you can use something like

```
.description-container {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -11%;
    transition: margin-top 5s linear;
}

.description-container.playing {
    margin-top: 0%;
}
```

1. That means that the transition applies on `margin-top` changes
2. The animation has a duration of 5 seconds
3. And has a `linear` speed curve